# Employer asking me to take less responsibility? Constructive dismissal?

Tags: human-resources

I was hired as a VP at a company to lead all aspects of a new business unit  - sales, marketing, operations and product development - centered around a new product line.  I am 6 months into the role and doing well, however the company's core business, which I am not a part of, is having a lot of challenges. The CEO would like to compensate for the eroding core business by accelerating my business unit in which he sees a lot of promise for the future.

The executive team is proposing that - to go faster and best use the full capabilities of the organization - we should 'fold in' my unit into the greater organization and redistribute my responsibilities to them (ie. my marketing responsibility would go to the VP of Marketing, my product development responsibility would go to VP Product, etc.)

If the CEO agrees, and all my responsibilities are redistributed to the various functional executives, I'm not sure yet what role I will have left, if any. One idea that came up is that I might play a product specialist role supporting sales, but this would be a different role with significantly less responsibility.

What are my options? Should I wait to see what new role is given to me? Discuss with my CEO proactively for a new role? If they keep me at my current title but change the role to be a small subset of the responsibility I was hired for, isn't that 'constructive dismissal' ?

Comment: If you got hired on as a VP you should have a golden parachute... if you don't then you are probably at will and have no options should they choose to terminate you

Answer (score 2):

What I read between lines is that there is idea of your CEO  of organizing BU on one side and idea of the rest of executive team  of redistributing BU functions on the other side.

Sounds that there is  in a matter of fact  the confrontation of concepts of organizing between your CEO  and others and that you personally are not the target.

It is more the battle of your CEO than it is yours.

Do you dispose with figures and analysis of these 6 months that support the survival of your BU?What are arguments of the opposite side?Are there facts that show that your BU does not make a profit?

You have to seriously analyse the existing position of your BU together with your CEO.So do contact him but not because only of your position, his is in a bigger jeopardy if BU fails.You have to work together in order to approve the  existence of this BU or you two fall in the package.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a standard political battle. The other VPs want to get your golden goose to cover their dying BU.

Discuss with the CEO as soon as possible.

You really want to stay in control of the stuff you built up. Now you have to convince the CEO that you are the man to lead this BU into a golden future, and that splitting it up and distributing the parts to the old guard would likely pull it down the drain too.

Focus on those points: The old guard needs to fix the core business. How should they do that while also building up your greenfield BU? Even just doing a successful knowledge transfer will harm the core business even more, while weakening your growing BU.

This will not be the last battle you fight. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It's not constructive dismissal, by definition that's..

"The changing of an employee's job or working conditions with the aim of forcing their resignation."

The way you have explained it sounds as if you have done a good job, and as such should be looking at how when more people get involved with this you can still take a senior stance in overseeing it.

Because it sounds like you haven't been with your employer very long if they wanted you gone in this capacity they would be better off making you redundant.

Comment: Making him redundant may still happen, *after* the transfer of responsibilities - that would be less disruptive than dropping him now.

Comment: Fair point, well presented